# C# MVC - Fetch name of property dynamically depending on model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, reflection, custom-attributes

In my MVC-project I have different custom validation-attributes. One of them is to check the value of a property against the value of another property.

As stated in many articles, I add something like

```
result.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty", _otherPropertyHtml);
result.ValidationParameters.Add("comparetype", _compareType);
result.ValidationParameters.Add("equalitytype", _equalityType);
```

to the returning `ModelClientValidationRule` object.

My problem now is, that - if my property to check - is encapsulated in another object, validation will not work.

If I create something like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValueOne)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ValueTwo)
```

validation will work fine as it renders

```
data-val-otherproperty="ValueTwo"
```

My problem is for the following

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IntermediateObject.ValueOne)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IntermediateObject.ValueTwo)
```

This will render two textboxes with names `IntermediateObject_ValueOne` and `IntermediateObject.ValueTwo`. But still data-val-otherproperty="ValueOne" for the first textbox.

How can it be achieved, that `data-val-otherproperty` has always the correct name of the other property?

My thoughts are something like HtmlHelper<>.NameFor(m => ...) or something that uses reflection?

**Update 1 - Added code as requested by comments**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustomCompareToOther : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    // private backing-field
    private readonly string _otherPropertyName;

    // constructor
    public OemCompareToOther(string otherPropertyName)
    {
        _otherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
    }

    // implementation of IClientValidatable
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var result = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName),
                ValidationType = "customcomparetoother"
            };

        // add the property-name so it is known when rendered for client-side validation
        result.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty", _otherPropertyHtml); // here I would need IntermediateObject.ValueTwo instead of only ValueTwo

        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Usage at model-level would be

```
public class MyModel
{
    [CustomCompareToOther("ValueOTwo", CompareType.NotEqual, PropertyType.String)]
    public string ValueOne { get; set; }    

    [CustomCompareToOther("ValueTwo", CompareType.NotEqual, PropertyType.String)]
    public string ValueTwo { get; set; }
}
```

And what I will put into my View would be something like

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public MyModel IntermediateObject { get; set; }
}
```

used e.g. `return View(new ViewModel())`.
So, in the rendered HTML I would have an input

```
<input type="text" name="IntermediateObject_ValueOne" id="IntermediateObject.ValueOne" data-val-customcomparetoother-otherpropertyname="ValueTwo" />
<input type="text" name="IntermediateObject_ValueTwo" id="IntermediateObject.ValueTwo" data-val-customcomparetoother-otherpropertyname="ValueOne" />
```

but I need

```
<input type="text" name="IntermediateObject_ValueOne" id="IntermediateObject.ValueOne" data-val-customcomparetoother-otherpropertyname="IntermediateObject.ValueTwo" />
<input type="text" name="IntermediateObject_ValueTwo" id="IntermediateObject.ValueTwo" data-val-customcomparetoother-otherpropertyname="IntermediateObject.ValueOne" />
```

in the html so javascript-validation can fetch the other property correctly.

Comment: why would you want to do this? if you have multiple models that have so much similarity, you should make them share a parent class, then you can make a view based on that parent

Comment: I have a request/response structure build up where my `Response` contains the `Request` that will be posted next. So, in my `View` I'll render `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Request.ValueOne)`. Sure, I could always add `"Request."` but I don't like magic strings, not all parts are currently request/response based and if the name changes from `Request` to `RenamedRequest`, nothing will work

Comment: Show all your attribute code

Comment: @AlexArt. I added the code (just example-code, not working in real) as Update 1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `[Compare("PropertyName")]` Data Annotation.

Example in your View Model:

```
[Display(Name = "New Password")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Compare("NewPassword")]
public string PasswordConfirmation { get; set; }
```

Just remember to add the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace to your using statements

Comment: (For me) there it's no option to change from custom-attribute I currently have to `CompareAttribute`